# How to move cursor position when printing data in Linux Terminal using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I wanna write a program that prints a timetable in the terminal. In order to print a table using ASCII characters, I need to move the printing cursor to a particular coordinate of the terminal.
for example, I want to have something like this in the output:

[image]

Could anybody help, please?
Any other idea for printing this table is also accepted.

Comment: in case you were wondering you can use a simple function like ```void GoTo(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << "\033[" << x << ";" << y << "H";
}``` to get yourself going.

Comment: @Rika could you please explain how does this piece of code work?

Comment: @Mehdi, please have a look [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk1gb1mdP)